# Hunchentoot : function does not work within webpage but is totally fine when used in slime

Tags: function, slime, hunchentoot

I am newly working with hunchentoot. 
Anyway i am doing a webpage for managing a simple todo list following  [this](http://www.adampetersen.se/articles/lispweb.htm)  tutorial.
I have a problem with my deletetodo function defined :

```
(defun deletetodo (todoid) (setf *todos* (remove (find todoid *todos* :test #'equal :key #'todocid) *todos*)))
```

When i run (deletetodo id) from slime it works perfect and the note get deleted.

But when i run it from my hunchertoot server it doesn't return any error but it doesn't delete anything !
this is my function for calling deletid page:

```
(define-url-fn (deleteid)
 (let ((id  (parameter "id")))
  (deletetodo id)
  (redirect "/menu.html")))
```

The following page was called with deleteid.html?id=1 , supposing 1 is an example.
I tried tracing the request and it's totally correct and the correct id is sent but deletetodo just don't work!
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel stupid :) 
it's just a formatting issue, the id value sent withing the request is in string format, but what is needed is an int.
So using (read-from-string id) fixes the issue.